# Charset of JSP tags

Tags: jsp, character-encoding, jsp-tags

Simple question about charset of JSP tags.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib  tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="custom" %>
<custom:mytag>  </custom:mytag>
```

`mytag` is simple .`tag` file located in `WEB-INF/tags`. Charset of this file in eclipse is UTF-8. For some reason UTF-8 symbols do not display properly.

This affect only including tags, another jsp-s that was included display fine

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`<%@tag pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` placed in your tag file will help.

[Tag directive attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html#wp89775) resemble ones of its `page` counterpart.

Comment: heh, it helped, i was trying "page" instead and it throws exception, of course. Did not know that there is tag directive

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the order of declaration of pageEncoding attribute. I figured out that pageEncoding attribute must be the first attribute declared right after @tag directive.

**Incorrect**: `<%@tag description="some description" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

**Correct:** `<%@tag pageEncoding="UTF-8"  description="some description"%>`