# double encoded UTF-8 output of tag file in jsp content

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding

I have some JSP pages properly encoded in UTF-8, verified using a Hex Editor, Eclipse and TextPad, with a proper pageEncoding and contentType attribute specifying UTF-8 each. Everything looked fine in the browser as well. Now I needed to extract some of the contents into JSP tag files, while the tag files itself again are properly encoded as UTF-8 and have a pageEncoding of UTF-8 each. I followed a documentation from Oracle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html#bname

The problem now is that e.g. german umlauts appear as double encoded UTF-8 in the browser, instead of an "ö" I see "Ã¶". If I change the pageEncoding to be windows-1252 in Eclipse, which itself seem to properly re-encode the file, again verified using TextPad and a Hex Editor, everything looks fine in the browser.

As tag files are used to automatically create Java source code for TagHandlers, I looked at the generated source code files and recognized that on pageEncoding UTF-8 the source file itself already contains double encoded UTF-8 for the german umlauts. The source file itself is encoded in UTF-8 and the out.write-statements for my german umlauts contain "Ã¶" if I view the source file in TextPad, which tells about UTF-8, too. If I open the source file in a Hex Editor I see the "Ã¶"-characters appear with more bytes, as should be expected with double encoded UTF-8.

The following is an example line from the generated source code file:

```
out.write("\t\t\t\t\ttitle=\"Verzeichnis lÃ¶schen\">\r\n");
```

I already changed some default encoding options of my Eclipse workspace, but without any effect. It seems to me that during source code generation of tag files the UTF-8 characters of the tag file itself are preserved, in opposite to how source code of JSP files gets generated. If I view the generated source code of JSP files with german umlauts they are properly shown as "ö" in TextPad, which recognizes the file encoded as UTF-8, or as "Ã¶" if I open the file in a Hex Editor.

I'm a bit lost here, does anyone has any idea on why UTF-8 encoded tag files are handled this way and differently to JSP files? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any hints!

**Some thinks to additionally mention:**

The tag files are still used in JSP files which are encoded as UTF-8 etc., therefore the content/encoding/whatever "around" the content produced by the tag files still is properly encoded UTF-8. As I said before, the contents of the tag files are simply some statements which worked perfectly well in a JSP file before.

Following are the statements with which I use my tag files:

```
<%@ taglib  tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/dirListing"
        prefix="dirListing"
%>
[...]
<dirListing:tree dir="${requestScope.dir}" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I understand your answer. The character "ö" is a single byte if it's encoded into ISO-8859-1 and not two, two bytes is UTF-8 and your lines with .getBytes("UTF-8") clearly convert a Java String from it's internal representation into UTF-8 and afterwards print the UTF-8 encoded bytes, and not characters anymore, as ISO-8859-1 characters. That's not a "ö" in ISO-8859-1, "ö" has the bytes F6 as can be clearly seen in the wikipedia.

Comment: Besides that, Eclipse, TextPad and a Hex Editor all three indicate that the tag file is encoded as UTF-8. If I change the pageEncoding directive of the tag file from UTF-8 to windows-1252 and vice versa the content of the files change, Eclipse recognizes the different encoding as well as TextPad does and my "ö" has two bytes on UTF-8 encoding and one byte on windows-1252 if I open the file in a hex editor. I may check this again tomorrow but I spent hours with making this sure today.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a pageEncoding directive, as suggested in the accepted answer to this question?

[Charset of JSP tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242682/charset-of-jsp-tags)

I do understand that your problem is not the correct interpretation of the tag encoding, but apparently that Eclipse encoded the file incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, I have pageEncoding directives in the JSP file and in the tag file. That's way I could test and see it works with windows-1252 in the tag file, which produces properly encoded UTF-8 in the generated Java source code and browser.